# Función que reciba 2 argumentos: una cadena y un objeto. Debe retornar un nuevo string reemplazando variables de la cadena con los valores del objeto

Tags: javascript

necesito una ayuda con este ejercicio.
Debo escribir una función llamada template que reciba dos argumentos: una cadena y un objeto. La función debe retornar una nueva cadena reemplazando las variables de la cadena de entrada con los valores definidos en el objeto.

Las variables vienen encerradas en corchetes [] dentro del texto.

```
template("Hola [nombre]", { nombre: "German" }); // => "Hola German"
template("Hola [nombre], tu saldo es [saldo]", { nombre: "German", saldo: 12000 }); // => "Hola German, tu saldo es 12000"
template("Hola mundo", {}) // => "Hola mundo"
```

Si la variable no viene definida en el objeto, aparece el texto "undefined" (que es lo que devuelve JavaScript por defecto cuando no se encuentra una llave en un objeto):

```
template("Hola [nombre]", {}); // => "Hola undefined"
```

Si sobran variables en el objeto simplemente se ignoran:

```
template("Hola mundo", { nombre: "German" }); // => "Hola mundo"
```

Esto es lo que he logrado hacer, ahí está tomando solo el primer valor del objeto pero si son más valores no he podido ver como hacerlo

```
    const expReg = /\[([^\]]+)]/g;

function template(str, obj) {
  if (Object.keys(obj).length === 0) {
    return str.replace(expReg, "undefined")
  } else {
    let arr = Object.values(obj)
    for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
      let val = arr[i]
      return str.replace(expReg, val)
    }
  }
}
```

Gracias por la ayuda

Answer (score 0):

Usando esta expresión regular `/\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/g`:

- `\[` - Corchete de apertura
- `[a-zA-Z]+` - Una o más letras, minúsculas o mayúsculas
- `\]` - Corchete de cierre
- El modificador `g` es para buscar en toda la cadena, si se omite, solo va a encontrar una

Con [.matchAll()](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) obtienes todas las coincidencias. Recorres cada coincidencia para verificar si [existe en el objeto](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/hasOwnProperty) y asignar el valor de remplazo.

```js
function template(str, obj = {}) {
    // Crear expresión regular
    let regEx = /\[[a-zA-Z]+\]/g;
    // Obtener todas las coincidencias en un arreglo
    let matches = [...str.matchAll(regEx)];
    // Recorrer coincidencias
    matches.forEach(match => {
        // Cada coincidencia es un arreglo con una cadena. Ej ["[nombre]"]
        // Tomar elemento y eliminar corchetes
        let property = match[0].substr(1, match[0].length - 2);
        // Obtener valor a asignar si existe en el objeto, de lo contrario, undefined
        let value = (obj.hasOwnProperty(property)) ? obj[property] : 'undefined';
        // Aplicar remplazo para esta coincidencia
        str = str.replace(`[${property}]`, value);
    });
    return str;
}

console.log(template("Hola [nombre]", { nombre: "German" }));
console.log(template("Hola [nombre], tu saldo es [saldo]", { nombre: "German", saldo: 12000 }));
console.log(template("Hola mundo", {}));
console.log(template("Hola [nombre]", {}));
```

Comment: Me podrías aclarar por favor por qué en matches se usa el spread, no me queda muy claro. Muy clara tu respuesta, muchas gracias

Comment: Leyendo el enlace que puse a la [documentación](https://developer.mozilla.org/es/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/matchAll) encuentras que `matchAll()` devuelve un iterador. Se desestructura con el operador `spread` para convertirlo en un arreglo.